# Regex in PHP: validating coordinate input

Tags: php, regex

My problem is I'm trying to validate input submitted on a form as semi-colon delimited coordinates. I only want to accept data that holds the following pattern:

```
1,2
1,2;3,4
1,2;3,4;5,6
```

etc.. up to any length of coordinates.

It should fail where the semi-colon or comma is in the wrong place...

e.g. `1;2;3,4`

I'm pretty new to both regex and PHP. I used regex101.com to come up with something what I have been trying is:

```
if (!preg_match('/(\d+,\d+;)*\d+,\d+/', $coordinateData)) {
    return;
}
```

This matches my pattern but it also matches when the semicolon is in the wrong place.

I would really appreciate help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/7ztCl7/3)

```
^(\d+,\d+)(?:;(?1))*$
```

It's pretty much the same as [`^\d+,\d+(?:;\d+,\d+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/7ztCl7/4) except:

1. You define the pattern once and reuse it
2. It's shorter
3. It's *slightly* slower (so using `^\d+,\d+(?:;\d+,\d+)*$` may improve performance)

Also, note that placing `(?:;\d+,\d+)*` at the end improves performance (as opposed to at the start like you have it).

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(\d+,\d+)` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `\d+` Match one or more digits
  - `,` Match this literally
  - `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `(?:;(?1))*` Match the following any number of times

  - `;` Match this literally
  - `(?1)` Recurse the first subpattern (contents of capture group 1)
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line